# Make HTML5 range input reset across page reloads

Tags: html

Is there a way to make an HTML5 slider (`input` range) tag reset its position across page reloads? As is, it stays in its last dragged-to position when you reload the page.

Comment: Try saving the value in a Server side SESSION variable or Client side Cookie.

Answer (score 3):

Use `autocomplete="off"`

for example:

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something else thats make your `Range Input` to maintain `value` across postback(reloads).

Because every time the form is reloaded the `Range Input` will be reseted.

Try

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form id="qweq">
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" step=""1 />
<input type="submit" text="reload"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

just runs these in your browser ,you will see on `submit` click the page `reloads` and `Input Range`
is reseted